# PHP is not applying Regex to check void string

Tags: php, regex

I made a regex [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Bz1GvOlzbM6Z9eDy) which allows:

- NP123
- FS-123
- FS-123-456
- or void

works well on Debuggex, but and I don't understand why PHP accept strings like "TEST" which is not part of the accepted templates

Check the fiddler: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/teA

Comment: First of all, your grouping is wrong. Next, the lookahead as a separate alternative looks wrong as well. Try `"~^(?:FS-[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?|NP[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?$~"` in code. I understand you want to match an empty string, too (not "void").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:FS-[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?|NP[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GEeegZ/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of an outer non-capturing group for the anchors to be applied to all the alternatives inside

  - `FS-[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?` - `FS-` and 1+ alphanumeric chars and then an optional sequence of `-` and  1+ alphanumeric chars
  - `|` - or
  - `NP[0-9a-zA-Z]+` - `NP` and 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `)?` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string.